# Eved Knani versus a Woman

Tags: blessing, women, mitzvah, shacharis-morning-prayer, slave-serve-eved-avadim

In terms of obligation in mitzvos, what is the difference between an Eved Knani and a woman? And if they are the same, why do we have two separate brachos for each in the morning prayers?

Comment: isn't freedom from being a slave a reason to be thankful?

Comment: also an eved is not necessarily born a slave. so he might have acquired the mitzvot later in life

Comment: @ray But that does not delineate between the two. What's the difference in terms of obligation?

Comment: The eved Kna'ani doesn't have the laws of niddah so I see a difference between an eved and a woman.

Comment: @Danno A women doesn't have the laws of Keri or Milah. (And for the record men and women are equally obligated not to be a partner in sex-with-a-niddah.)

Comment: @DoubleAA yes, these are other distinctions. I'm not sure how that relates, though. The questionm was about differentiating between an eved kna'ani and a woman, not between a man and a woman. If your point is that an eved kna'ani is mchuyav in all the things a Jewish man is, then that would be your overall answer to the question.

Comment: @Danno My point was the only distinctions you drew were gender ones, ie. not so related.

Comment: @DoubleAA so is kinyan a better area for distinctions? The eved can't make one and retain things -- they are his master's. A woman can. At least an unmarried woman -- a married woman may, depending on all sorts of variables if I remember correctly.

Comment: @DoubleAA Maybe even better is the sub category of mitzvot aseh shehazman grama that a women is obligated in.

Comment: devirkahan, you question includes an unspoken assumption that the morning blessings are thanks for levels of _mitzva_ obligation. Including that assumption explicitly in your question would clarify it for more readers; citing a source for it would be even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [שלמי חגיגה](http://hebrewbooks.org/47994) in 6:(4) (starting on [page 30](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47994&st=&pgnum=38)) has 2 long pieces discussing this – and from what I understand, women and Eved Knani are incidentally similar in their obligations.

(Not completely incidental, as their dispensations have the same source: both the Eved Knani and the Married Woman have another Boss besides for the Torah. He discusses that too.)

He brings – based on Rishonim – that an Eved Knani is either a non-Jew with some Jewish obligations or else "2nd class" Jew with limited obligations.

Either way, an Eved Knani is not a **fully fledged** Jew - and is therefore on a higher level than a non-Jew but a lower level than a Jewish woman.

As a result, the Bracha for Eved Knani is between the one where we thank for not being non-Jews with no obligations, and the one where we [men] thank for not being women who are fully fledged Jews with certain dispensations.